# Drop-Down menu disappears when hovering

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my drop-down menu. When I hover over the menu it disappears after the second line. I'm not sure what I should do to change it.

here is the HTML:

```
 <nav id="nav-wrap">

           <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
            <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

           <ul id="nav" class="nav">

               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
              <li class="current"><span><a href="portfolio-index.html">Resources</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="alcoholre.html">Alcohol</a></li>
                    <li><a href="drugsre.html">Drugs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mentalhealthre.html">Mental Health</a></li>
                    <li><a href="suicidere.html">Suicide</a>
                 </ul>
              </li>
               <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

           </ul> <!-- end #nav -->
```

And here is the CSS

```
  ul#nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  min-width: 100%;

  border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;

/* for transition effects */
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);

-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

 /* Third level sub menu
 ul#nav ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 100%;

 border-radius: 15px 3px 3px 3px;
 }
 */

 ul#nav ul li {
padding: 0;
display: block;
text-align: center;

/* for transition effects */
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;

-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

/*On Hover */
ul#nav li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
ul#nav li:hover > ul li {
height: 42px;
overflow: visible;
border-bottom: 1px solid #26272C;
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul li:last-child  { border: none; }

/* Sub Menu Anchor links */
ul#nav ul li a {
padding: 6px 15px;
margin: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWOOOE

Comment: Add a working demo

Comment: It is the `overflow: hidden;` you have on the `li` that cause that

Comment: I tried changing that but it did not work. I think it has something to do with the last child, but it might also be elsewhere within the program. I will have to keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Working example of your question. [github](https://abinthaha.github.io/Menu-Dropdown/)

Achieved using HTML5 and CSS3

Comment: Yeah that's what I am looking for. I am not sure what the issue is. I'm beginning to wonder if it isn't within this portion. I went through and copied the HTML and CSS  from the example you posted, but still had a similar result.